# How do I troubleshoot a KernelBase.exe Fault? (Exception code: 53534f)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

We are getting the following error from a .NET Application:

```
Faulting application name: OurApplication.exe, version: 1.0.10603.0, time stamp: 0x556f0756 
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18409, time stamp: 0x53159a86 

Exception code: 0xe053534f 
Fault offset: 0x0000c42d 
Faulting process id: 0x 
Faulting application start time: 0x 
Faulting application path: 
Faulting module path: 
Report Id:
```

OurApplication.exe has a handler for `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` and `Application.ThreadException`. What am I missing?

Comment: Nothing, really. That's an exception that is not passed to your application. We've had the same problem and have not found a proper solution, other than updating to the latest framework (our application was .NET 2.0 at that time).

Comment: What's with the c++; c; and VB.NET tags?

Comment: more info please, what was you doing when you got such exception?, I had it 2 times one was a privilege problem and the other was corruption in the windows system after sp2 and that was fixed by reinstalling the system.

Comment: The exception code tells the tale, 53534f are the ASCII codes for "SSO".  A Soft Stack Overflow.  Midly softer than a hard stack overflow, the runtime can tell that a hard stack overflow is guaranteed when setting up the stack frame for a call.  No space left to make the call so it pulls the plug early.   Otherwise treated the exact same way, StackOverflowException is a fatal error and always instantly crashes your app.  Always a bug in your code, there are *many* questions about it here.

Comment: Wow, @HansPassant , how the heck did you know what that error code meant. I googled this and came up with squat. Feel free to post this as the answer. So you are thinking this is a stack overflow, hmmm...

Comment: @MickyDuncan- it's called an act of desperation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Hans Passant:

The exception code tells the tale, 53534f are the ASCII codes for "SSO". A Soft Stack Overflow. Midly softer than a hard stack overflow, the runtime can tell that a hard stack overflow is guaranteed when setting up the stack frame for a call. No space left to make the call so it pulls the plug early. Otherwise treated the exact same way, StackOverflowException is a fatal error and always instantly crashes your app. Always a bug in your code, there are many questions about it here

This was also a great article:
http://blog.fogcreek.com/production-debugging-a-story-about-exception-code-0xe053534f/